# Error: 3D Matlab array to 0 dimensional np array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array, transform

I'm having an issue transforming 3 dimensional matlab array into a 3 dimensional np array in python. When I read it in, an error message shows me it is a 0 dimensional np array.

This is the code I am using:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np 

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('2021.01.25.FC.mat')
matrix = np.array(mat)
```

However, when I index the array like this:

```
x=matrix[2,2,2]
```

I receive this error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

Does any one know the reason why this array is being read in as a 0 dimensional array in numpy or how to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: Examine `mat` first.  Don't forget to read the `loadmat` docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is due to 'mat' being a dictionary as the [scipy.io.loadmat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) documentation suggests.

'mat' is likely a dictionary that stores all the variables present in your '2021.01.25.FC.mat' file. If the matrix you are interested in is named "MyMatrix" in your matlab file then a quick fix could be:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np 

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('2021.01.25.FC.mat')['MyMatrix']
matrix = np.array(mat)
```